# Bigcommerce API Authenticating a customer with GET request

Tags: rest, bigcommerce

I'm doing a `GET` for customers with a given email address (there will only be one). Before displaying the returned information, I need to authenticate the user, but I can't see a way in the docs that allows providing a password as a parameter to a `GET`. In fact It only seems to be possible to provide a password when creating (`POST`ing) or updating (`PUT`ting) a customer. Is it possible to authenticate customers via the API this way?

Answer (score 0):

from what I understand - _authentication is only supported for POST and PUT on customer objects. I believe it is intended to create a customer who can login and stuff like that.

Can you explain your use case and maybe there is a workaround..

Comment: In my payment process, I'm asking if the user has an account, if so to enter their email, which I use as the parameter for the GET in order to determine the shipping address. However I really need to be authenticating their password before showing their details. Thanks for your help